# What other games can I play with the zombies from Zombies?

Tags: zombies

What other games can I play with the zombies from Zombies?

It seems like a waste to have so many of the little guys and not use them to maximum effect.

What other rulesets or alternate games are people playing with their zombies?

Answer (score 3):

What *can't* you do with a giant pile of zombies?  If you do the table-top RPG thing regularly, the zombies make great generic bad guys.  Some friends of mine created a variant of [Frag](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2025/frag) called Frag Zombies that used plenty of the zombie figures during the game.  Pretty much any board game that uses miniatures is a potential use case for the zombies.  Imagine playing a zombie in Monopoly.  You could build a Zombie army in Risk.  How about using the glow-in-the-dark zombies in a game of Last Night on Earth?  The possibilities are endless.